# Sending a Mail using SMTP PHP phpmailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, mail-server

I want to be able to send a mail to my Email address whenever I fill in and submit my contact form. I followed a tutorial on how to do that but unfortunately it does not send a mail to mailbox. Everytime I submit the form it justs returns the error message 'There is an error' Can someone please check this code to find out what can be the problem?

Here is the php code

```
        <?php
            //index.php

            $error = '';
            $name = '';
            $email = '';
            $subject = '';
            $message = '';

            function clean_text($string)
            {
            $string = trim($string);
            $string = stripslashes($string);
            $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
            return $string;
            }

            if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
            {
            if(empty($_POST["name"]))
            {
                $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter your Name</label></p>';
            }
            else
            {
                $name = clean_text($_POST["name"]);
                if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
                {
                    $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Only letters and white space allowed</label></p>';
                }
            }
            if(empty($_POST["email"]))
            {
                $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter your Email</label></p>';
            }
            else
            {
                $email = clean_text($_POST["email"]);
                if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                {
                    $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Invalid email format</label></p>';
                }
            }
            if(empty($_POST["subject"]))
            {
                $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Subject is required</label></p>';
            }
            else
            {
                $subject = clean_text($_POST["subject"]);
            }
            if(empty($_POST["message"]))
            {
                $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Message is required</label></p>';
            }
            else
            {
                $message = clean_text($_POST["message"]);
            }
            if($error == '')
            {
                require 'class/class.phpmailer.php';
                $mail = new PHPMailer;
                $mail->IsSMTP();                                //Sets Mailer to send message using SMTP
                $mail->Host = 'kwchems.com';        //Sets the SMTP hosts of your Email hosting, this for Godaddy
                $mail->Port = '465';                                //Sets the default SMTP server port
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         //Sets SMTP authentication. Utilizes the Username and Password variables
                $mail->Username = 'info@kwchems.com';                   //Sets SMTP username
                $mail->Password = 'txpxbaron45';                    //Sets SMTP password
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                          //Sets connection prefix. Options are "", "ssl" or "tls"
                $mail->From = $_POST["email"];                  //Sets the From email address for the message
                $mail->FromName = $_POST["name"];               //Sets the From name of the message
                $mail->AddAddress('info@kwchems.com', 'Name');      //Adds a "To" address
                $mail->AddCC($_POST["email"], $_POST["name"]);  //Adds a "Cc" address
                $mail->WordWrap = 50;                           //Sets word wrapping on the body of the message to a given number of characters
                $mail->IsHTML(true);                            //Sets message type to HTML             
                $mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];             //Sets the Subject of the message
                $mail->Body = $_POST["message"];                //An HTML or plain text message body
                if($mail->Send())                               //Send an Email. Return true on success or false on error
                {
                    $error = '<label class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us</label>';
                }
                else
                {
                    $error = '<label class="text-danger">There is an Error</label>';
                }
                $name = '';
                $email = '';
                $subject = '';
                $message = '';
            }
            }

    ?>
```

Here is my form

```
<div class="contact-form">
                <?php echo $error; ?>

        <h2>Contact Us (* Required Field)</h2>

            <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
                <div>
                    <span><label>Your name*</label></span>
                    <span><input type="text" name="name"  value="<?php echo $name; ?>" style=" padding:8px; border-radius:5px;"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span><label>Your email*</label></span>
                    <span><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" style=" padding:8px; border-radius:5px;"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span><label>Company:</label></span>
                    <span><input type="text" name="company" value="<?php echo $company; ?>" style=" padding:8px; border-radius:5px;"</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span><label>Country*:</label></span>
                    <span><input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $country; ?>" style=" padding:8px; border-radius:5px;"</span>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <span><label>Phone:</label></span>
                    <span><input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>"  style=" padding:8px; border-radius:5px;"</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span><label>SUBJECT*</label></span>
                    <span><input type="text" name="subject" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>" style=" padding:8px; border-radius:5px;"</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span><label>Type Your Message Please*</label></span>
                    <span><textarea name="message"> <?php echo $message; ?></textarea></span>
                </div>
               <div>
                    <span><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"></span>
              </div>
            </form>


      </div>
```

Comment: Display the contents of `$mail->ErrorInfo` after a send failure, just as the code examples do. It also looks like you have based your code on a obsolete example, so make sure you’re running the latest version of PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

Please change this line.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

To:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

Put code in try and catch block as:

```
try {

 require 'class/class.phpmailer.php';
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->IsSMTP();                                //Sets Mailer to send message using SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'kwchems.com';        //Sets the SMTP hosts of your Email hosting, this for Godaddy
            $mail->Port = '465';                                //Sets the default SMTP server port
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         //Sets SMTP authentication. Utilizes the Username and Password variables
            $mail->Username = 'info@kwchems.com';                   //Sets SMTP username
            $mail->Password = 'txpxbaron45';                    //Sets SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                          //Sets connection prefix. Options are "", "ssl" or "tls"
            $mail->From = $_POST["email"];                  //Sets the From email address for the message
            $mail->FromName = $_POST["name"];               //Sets the From name of the message
            $mail->AddAddress('info@kwchems.com', 'Name');      //Adds a "To" address
            $mail->AddCC($_POST["email"], $_POST["name"]);  //Adds a "Cc" address
            $mail->WordWrap = 50;                           //Sets word wrapping on the body of the message to a given number of characters
            $mail->IsHTML(true);                            //Sets message type to HTML             
            $mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];             //Sets the Subject of the message
            $mail->Body = $_POST["message"];                //An HTML or plain text message body
            if($mail->Send())                               //Send an Email. Return true on success or false on error
            {
                $error = '<label class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us</label>';
            }
            else
            {
                $error = '<label class="text-danger">There is an Error</label>';
            }
            $name = '';
            $email = '';
            $subject = '';
            $message = '';

} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

The **true** param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just tried that but unfortunately , it will load the page and return an HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: PHPMailer uses Exceptions.

Comment: please remove if and else then it will actual error.

Comment: the if and else before the try?

Comment: This isn’t an answer.